# Excitation of a superconducting circuit

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

What do we mean by exciting a superconducting circuit--which represent a qubit, how they are get excited inside? how the two states of the qubit are represented in this circuit?

Comment: I think this question is very broad, a superconducting qubit behaves like an quantum anharmonic oscillator, you can find a lot of the theory for example [here](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~martinisgroup/classnotes/finland/LesHouchesJunctionPhysics.pdf)

Comment: For a simple type of SC qubit (Cooper Pair Box), the device consists of a superconducting island connected to the mainland by a Josephson junction. Then the states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ directly map to "cooper pair not on island" and "cooper pair on island" respectively